# Between Function on VARCHAR in MySQL

Tags: mysql

This is my table:

```
id    Name    salary
------------------------------------
B101    mob    10000
B1000   John   1000000 
B1002   flip   10000
B1030   Bean   100000
```

This is my query:

```
Select * from table 
where table.id >= 'B1000' and
table.id <= 'B1050'
```

This is the result I'm expecting:

```
id    Name    salary
------------------------------------
B1000   John   1000000 
B1002   flip   10000
B1030   Bean   100000
```

This is what I'm getting:

```
id    Name    salary
------------------------------------
B1000   John   1000000 
B101    mob    10000 
B1002   flip   10000
B1030   Bean   100000
```

How can I get the expected result?

Comment: Have a numeric id instead

Comment: is column `id` always start with *B* and followed by number?

Comment: Yes column id is always starting with B and followed by number

Comment: I cant able to do that change of column id to numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if column *id* always start with B (or another characters) and followed by numbers then you can try this :

```
Select * from table 
where substr(table.id,2,length(table.id) - 1) >= 1000
and substr(table.id,2,length(table.id) - 1) <= 1050
```

Explanation :
Let say you have sample data like this :

```
id
---------
A67
B32132
C89163
```

This query :

```
select substr(table.id,2,length(table.id) - 1) as id from table
```

Would produce :

```
id
----------
67
32132
89163
```

Which *2* in `..substr(table.id,2...` means starts from characters 2 in column id.
If column ID has more than one characters (let say 3 characters) like

```
id
-----------
Azx67
Byx32132
Czx89163
```

You need this query :

```
select substr(table.id,4,length(table.id) - 3) as id from table
```

To produce

```
id
-------------
67
32132
89163
```

Which *4* in `..substr(table.id,4...` means starts from characters 4 in column id.
Please note that the column should have a pattern. If the sample data like :

```
id
--------
A123
BB123
CCC23
```

You need more complex query to achieve desired result. And actually, it's not recommended to fill *id* column like that.

You can add this in *where clause* like :

```
Select * from table 
where substr(table.id,3,length(table.id) - 2) >= 1000 --start from characters 3 in column id
and substr(table.id,3,length(table.id) - 2) <= 1050 --start from characters 3 in column id
```

Comment: @debin i updated my answer. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @debin have you try it? because i already tried in your fiddle. dont forget to replace `table` to `table1` in your fiddle. goodluck!

Comment: Can anybody help me if I have more than one character before the Numbers?

Answer (score 0):

B101 would appear in a dictionary after B1000! You could do something messy like pre padding with zeroes or treating the numeric and alphabetic values separately.